# How to grep for a long html string with quotes and carriage returns

Tags: linux, grep

I need to recursively find all files that contain the following HTML:

```
<html id="blx-5fb3c619e82a2863d6567c52-000000001" class="blx-5fb3c619e82a2863d6567c52">
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="google" value="notranslate">
```

I'm trying the following with no success:

```
grep --include=\*.html -FRnw "/path-to-dir" -e '<html id="blx-5fb3c619e82a2863d6567c52-000000001" class="blx-5fb3c619e82a2863d6567c52">\n    <head>\n    <meta charset="utf-8">\n    <meta name="google" value="notranslate">'
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: `grep` processes the file one line at a time, it can't do multi-line matches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With GNU grep. Remove `-F`, `-n` and `"/path-to-dir"` and add `-Poz`.